# DeepLabCut No Images Created when extracting frames

Tags: python, windows-11

I am using DLC2.2.2 in Win11, and running as admin.

I run

```
deeplabcut.extract_frames(config_path, mode='automatic', algo='kmeans', userfeedback=True, crop=False)
```

and it says:

```
Frames were successfully extracted, for the videos listed in the config.yaml file.

You can now label the frames using the function 'label_frames' (Note, you should label frames extracted from diverse videos (and many videos; we do not recommend training on single videos!)).
```

But there are no frame be created in the 'labeled-data' folds.

Please help me to solve this problem!!

Answer (score 0):

Actully, It was caused by a stupid mistake.
When it ask you :

```
Do you want to extract (perhaps additional) frames for video: XXX.mp4 ?
yes/no
```

You should answer it in whole word 'yes' or 'no', not only 'y' or 'n'.